# Bootstrap horizontal form in modal layout padding issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having issues laying out a form the way I want in bootstrap v3.

Please see my example code here (click edit to see the form): http://bootply.com/112023

I have a modal with a form inside. I'm trying to split the row columns so that the form inputs all fit on one row, as well as looking correctly spaced. My problem is that the last element, the "x" button keeps moving onto a new row. Why is this, I thought bootstrap requires rows to add up to 12 and in this case it does. I have a feeling me nesting the rows this way is causing padding issues perhaps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using Chrome Dev Tools you can see that the second `col-xs-6` in your modal has a width of 294px. The Bootstrap class `col-xx-1` has the with of 8% which should be around 25px out of that 294px. However cols in BS have padding left and right of 15px so even if your 'col-xx-1' elements have a width of 0, because of padding they'll grow to 30px which is larger than 8% of the container width and that's why they don't fit.

The solution is to reduce the padding on those elements using CSS, don't rely on Bootstrap alone.